# How do I implicitly change an instance attribute by modifying another attribute of which it is comprised?

Tags: python, attributes, instance, implicit, mutated

So I have a class and initiate the instances to have attributes as described:

```
class Orders():

    def __init__(self, country='USA', product='Shoes'):
        self.profile = 'https://website.com/user'
        self.token = 'leHAiOjE2Nz'
        self.country = country
        self.product = product
        self.order_id = ''
        self.check_order = 'https://website.com/user/orders/' + self.order_id
```

When I then change the value of order_id, self.check_order is still assigned to the string + original order_id.

```
session1 = Orders()
print(id(session1.check), f'{session1.check=}')
print(id(session1.order_id), f'{session1.order_id=}')
session1.order_id = '123333079'
print(id(session1.order_id), f'new {session1.order_id=}')
print(id(session1.check), f'{session1.check=}')
```

yields

```
1726088546304 session1.check='https://website.com/user/orders/'
1725654976112 session1.order_id=''
1725660870256 new session1.order_id='123333079'
1726088546304 session1.check='https://website.com/user/orders/'
```

As you can see, session1.check is the same.

The only way I've found to modify it is with an explicit reassignment:

session1.check = session1.check+session1.order_id

However, this is not desirable as I would want this change to be implicit due to the nature of the method structure and mutations I need to perform on these attributes. I've watched Ned Batchelder's pycon presentation on names vs. values but I am stumped on how to make this work implicitly. There must be an elegant solution.

Comment: Sounds like you want a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: You should just use a method